# How create a user and limit the number of sessions in Informix Database

Tags: informix

Please guide me below things.

We can create the database user in Informix in OS level and Database level. Which is the best way and guide, how to create a new user in informix?

How to limit the number of sessions for Informix database?

Answer (score 2):

These links from the Informix 14.10 documentation describe how to do it:

CREATE USER

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1821.htm

USERMAPPING

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_1101.htm#ids_adr_1101

LIMITNUMSESSIONS

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1221.htm

Comment: Please guide me below things.How to limit the number of sessions per user wise ?

Is it possible in Informix?

Comment: Thank you. The explanation you provided, how to limit the number of sessions per database. Please guide me below things.How to limit the number of sessions per user wise ?

Is it possible in Informix?

Comment: Umm ... I don't recall any option to limit the number of connections per individual user. Not even within the multitenancy feature.